# Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on Dual Boot: Xbox Controller with wireless adapter always needs pairing after using Ubuntu then going to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I've got Ubuntu 20.04 and Win 10 on dual boot. I've also got a Xbox One Controller which I use on Windows with the official Wireless Adapter.

Everytime I boot into Linux, and then go back to Windows, I have to pair again the controller. If I'm on Windows and I restart and go into Windows again, I don't have to do this.

I don't wish to use the controller on Ubuntu, I just want it to work without a new pairing after previously having used Ubuntu.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue and I think I found a solution.

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105694/how-to-disable-a-usb-sound-device-with-udev) some friendly folks described how to disable usb devices on linux. So basically you have to:

- use `lsusb` to list usb devices in terminal.
- Identify the xbox dongle

  - For me it was: `Bus 003 Device 007: ID 045e:02e6 Microsoft Corp. Wireless XBox Controller Dongle`
- create a file (e.g. my.rules) in /etc/udev/rules.d/
- add this line to the file:
  `ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="045e", ATTR{idProduct}=="02e6", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo 0 >/sys/\$devpath/authorized'"` where the vendor id and product id correspond to the dongle's ID which we got from lsusb
- reboot & pair the controller one last time in windows

After doing these steps I don't need to re-pair my controller between ubuntu & linux boots anymore.

Comment: Perfect, this was it, thanks.  As a bonus, it still works with [xone](https://github.com/medusalix/xone) so you can use the controller with both Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: Works for me too, although there is a missing close `"` at the end, in the line to be added  to the file

Comment: thanks, i edited my answer to correct it